# I want to make a flowchart application in a browser. Which SVG Library to use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

As a fun project, I am going to make a simple flowchart app to learn some new html features, but I am unsure whether this is more appropriate for canvas or SVG (and which lib to use).

I believe that SVG is more appropriate here since everything is basically shapes connected to lines (sounds like vector graphics to me), but if you think otherwise let me know why.

As for libraries, I read the Raphael vs Jquery SVG library debate on here... but this took place a year and a half ago. What are your thoughts on the current state of these libraries or a newer one that has matured?

Comment: What browser support are you going for?

Answer (score 4):

Seems, to me at least, that Raphael is leading the pack.  I've read a few articles about it in JSMag and it seems that the library continues to evolve.  Raphael also seems to have a strong community backing and some decent activity on it's discussion board.  jQuery SVG's library hasn't had an update since January of 2010, so I'm not sure what it's current state of development is.

Also, looks like Raphael has some serious backing, whereas jQuery SVG looks to be a single person's work.  I'm not knocking it, so please don't get me wrong - it's just if I'm looking to build something for the long-term, I'd probably favor Raphael since it seems to have the stronger community backing.

Just my 2 cents.  Hope this helps.